# XSD use="optional"

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following:

```
<xs:attribute name="CarTitleID" type="xs:long" use="optional" />
```

In my source XML I want to allow people to say

```
<car CarTitleID="">
```

And have the XSD not fail.  Is this possible?

Comment: In other words CarTitleID="" is the same as not even specifying a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC this sort of thing is intended to be handled by [nillable types](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#Nils) but the implementation is not very practical ultimately.